# can i refresh a table from presently showing model-popup

Tags: ajax, html

I need to reload a table or div inside a model popup continuously, i failed with my code can you help me....

i tried with ajax ..code is below but its is not updating chats (i am doing a chat task)

```
**My Ajax code to check new message is or not** 

function check_msg()
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo site_url('member/check_message')?>/",
datatype: "JSON",
success: function(data) {
data = JSON.parse(data);

if(data.MsgStatus == "1")
{       
    $('#newchat').ajax.reload();                        
   } });}
   **HTML**
     <div class="modal-body form">
            <form action="#" id="chatform" class="form-horizontal">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="UserId"/> 
                <div class="form-body">
            <div class="container" id="container">
                <table id="newchat">
                    <div class="Scroll" id="Scroll">
               <div id="messagesout"></div>                               

                         </div>   </table>      </div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function reload_table()
{
 table.ajax.reload(); 
}
```

Use this code in your ajax and call it